# SqlBulkCopy error: The locale id '0' of the source column .. and the locale id '1033' of the destination column .. do not match

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I know there are similar questions but I still haven't found the answer to this problem.
My setup is the following.

Source table:

[image]

Destination table:

[image]

**SqlBulkCopy** call:

```
using (var destination = new SqlConnection(builderDestinationConnectionString.ConnectionString))
{
    try
    {
        destination.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        ...
    }

    using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(myConnectionString))
    {
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationToken();
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destinationTableName;
        bulkCopy.BatchSize = batchSize ?? GlobalContext.Configuration.BulkCopyBatchSize;
        bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = GlobalContext.Configuration.BulkCopyTimeout;
        bulkCopy.EnableStreaming = true;
        bulkCopy.NotifyAfter = GlobalContext.Configuration.BulkCopyNotifyLimit;
        bulkCopy.SqlRowsCopied += new SqlRowsCopiedEventHandler((sender, args) => myContext.Log.Info($"{args.RowsCopied} rows copied to {destinationTableName}"));

        try
        {
            await bulkCopy
                    .WriteToServerAsync(reader, cancellationTokenSource)
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**Working scenario**:

If my reader executes the query **SELECT * FROM BulkTable** the sqlBulkCopy works fine.

**Non-working scenario**:

this logic must be generic and sometimes I am using a select query that joins different tables and therefore I don't want an **Id**. Therefore I tried this query instead of SELECT *:

```
SELECT CONVERT([VARCHAR](50), [SomeString]) AS [SomeString]
      ,CONVERT([DATETIME], [SomeDate]) AS [SomeDate]
      ,CONVERT([INT], [SomeInt]) AS [SomeInt]
      ,CONVERT([FLOAT], [SomeFloat]) AS [SomeFloat]
      ,CONVERT([TEXT], [SomeText]) AS [SomeText]
      ,CONVERT([DECIMAL](18, 8), [SomeDecimal]) AS [SomeDecimal]
    FROM BulkTable
```

And the error is:

> The locale id '0' of the source column 'SomeDate' and the locale id '1033' of the destination column 'SomeString' do not match

I am not using KeepIdentity in the SqlBulkCopy on purpose in such a way the destination table can generate its own identity, but still nothing.

I don't want to use ColumnMappings in the BulkCopy because as mentioned this logic must remain generic to allow different sources/destinations and therefore columns.

Comment: If you want to keep it generic then execute the statement first with `sp_describe_first_result_set` to get the source columns that you can use to build the ColumnMappings for SqlBulkCopy.

Comment: I don't think there's much way around this, [since](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.columnmappings): _If the data source and the destination table have the same number of columns, and the ordinal position of each source column within the data source matches the ordinal position of the corresponding destination column, the ColumnMappings collection is unnecessary. However, if the column counts differ, or the ordinal positions are not consistent, you must use ColumnMappings to make sure that data is copied into the correct columns._

Comment: if an answer helped solve the problem, would you please mark as 'accepted'. Otherwise, pehaps a clarification would help get it resolved. thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your error you have 2x different column names referenced in source & destination, so you have a column algnment issue when you drop the ID.

Column alignment: the columns are being mapped positionally & in your non-working scenario when you dropped the ID the data is just left shifted one column.

Leading to somestring -> id, then somedate -> somestring.

Usually it results in a type casting error, but here it appears to have detected a locale mismatch between the columns first.

You can either: drop the ID from the destination or pad a dummy int as the first column in your select (or use some other rownum function).
Or just pull the ID across & ignore it (rename the destination column to avoid confusion if it may contain duplicate values due to the multiple source tables involved).

Comment: The padding with a fake ID column works! Do you have an example on how to use rownum functions to affect the SqlBulkCopy ?

Comment: The addition of a row number eg,    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER  ([SomeDate]), CONVERT([VARCHAR](50), [SomeString]) AS [SomeString]     is just another way of filling your fake ID column., only useful you wanted to populate with a different value per row on import and can manage the duplicates that could be loaded if the routine runs multiple times. The sort order is arbitrary but required, so pick a field with the least cost for sorting - note that this overhead can be problematic with large datasets.